# RealSense R200 crashes with high color resolution and low depth resolution

Tags: c++, realsense

I'm currently working on a program that uses both color and depth streams of the **Intel RealSense R200**. I want to use the lowest **depth resolution 240p**, since it has less noise than higher resolutions. However, when using it in combination with a **1080p resolution** for the **color** stream, **the sensor suddenly stops acquiring frames** for some reason.

In detail, the method ***PXCSenseManager::AcquireFrame()*** at some points blocks for about 10 seconds before returning with error code -301 (i.e. *"Execution aborted due to errors in upstream components"*).

Higher depth resolutions or lower color resolutions seem to work fine, but resulting either in more noise for the depth data or less quality for the color data. This problem occurs not only within my code, but also in the official RSSDK, namely *DF_RawStreams* and *DF_CameraViewer*.

Has anyone of you experienced the same problem and if yes, do you know a way to solve it? Unfortunately I haven't yet been able to find anything dealing with this kind of problem.

My PC has following specs:

1. Motherboard:

   - Mouse Computer Ltd. H110M-S01
2. CPU:

   - Intel® Core™ i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
3. Memory:

   - 16GB RAM DDR3
4. Graphics card:

   - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 4GB GDDR5

Thank you very much in advance

PS: It's my first question to ask on StackOverflow, so I'd appreciate any feedback :) Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a question for the developers of the R200 API. I'll see if I can reproduce this tomorrow.

Comment: @ChrisStathis Thank you, I really appreciate your efforts :) Btw, the same problem occurs on other PCs, too.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply in the Intel forum that says:

> Are you using Windows 10 Anniversary Update? It may be because of a bug in that causing some cameras to crash. Try running your app on a PC which hasn't updated in the last few weeks. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any current fixes. Apparently, Microsoft are planning on pushing another update which fixes this issue (amongst others) sometime in September.

When checking other PCs that haven't been applied the Anniversary update, the software worked well without any crash. I guess I should wait for Microsoft to provide a patch that fixes the camera crash issue.

However, please feel free to reply, if you have got anything to comment regarding this problem :)

Comment: Microsoft already provided a patch [KB3176938](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3176938) a week ago. See [this thread](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/216), which might be related and suggests disabling Frame Server.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply :)
Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, either. I have both the update and the registry entry, but nothing has any effect.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that even last MS patch has issues and change the pre-Anniversary behavior. It might also so happen that the problem is more Intel's, not Microsoft's. Either way, one thing you could re-check is that you have EnableFrameServerMode two registry entries, not just one. With and without Wow6432Node, for 32 and 64 bit apps. If this does not work you might have to wait for solution from either Intel or Microsoft, or some volunteer would discover another way around the new changes.